# Attribute name is not visible while executing sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using **sqlite3** for database for my web app using **flask**. While running a query , i get the result but with no attribute names on the top,

```
CREATE TABLE registrants (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, pass_hash TEXT NOT NULL, points INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 50);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
sqlite> select * from registrants;
1|Vasanthan|srvasanthan33|pbkdf2:sha256:260000$lt38hpgeNvQYtJ9g$f8d68b0fde765e525110cfd1619421b1aa1a1db0beae2fb0382c49b5db03b96c|50
sqlite>
```

I am expecting to get a output with neat table with attrubute name of table on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the output mode with the special `.mode`  command from the CLI.
For example:

```
sqlite> .mode table
```

There are other option in the output format. For more information you can look at the help for this command:

```
.help .mode
```